# I want to have magic move animate cropping and image/changing its mask

Tags: keynote, crop

This would essentially enable me to do things like:

1. simulate scrolling a web page
2. prezi style panning (without it having to be for the whole friggin presentation)

It does not seem possible to animate image properties? (crop/mask position)

Comment: this one is sort of close: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231592/13096 I did something similar: I wanted to show the first region of an image on liek the left most 30% of the slide. The next slide I wanted to whole slide to have another region. So i made the mask as large as the whole slide, but positioned it in the first slide so that only some of it was on the slide. Then on the next slide, i move the whole masked area onto the slide and move which part is visible in mask, and magic move figured it out.

Comment: This is also related: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2151109